# How do I change a custom View color at runtime?

Tags: android, view, drawable

My class is defined as the following:

```
public class Island extends View {
    private ShapeDrawable mDrawable;

    public Island(Context context) {
        super(context);
        int width = 50;
        int height = 50;

        mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
        mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    public void change() {
        mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        mDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }
```

Why won't the shape change colors when I call change() on the object? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to call invalidate so the view knows that it needs to redraw

Comment: That was it, thanks. Before, I was trying to call invalidateself() on the drawable itself, but calling invalidate() on the View worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your object is ,
Island island = new Island(context);

To update your view you can either call island.onDraw() 
Or
island.invalidate();

If you are changing this from another thread then you can use postInvalidate() method .